# Faculty transition between two universities

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, adjunct-faculty

I am moving to another university (US-Engineering) and have a few active proposals in my current institution. It seems I cannot move a part of these proposals. I was wondering if I still can use the money toward, let's say summer salary and conference if I keep an adjunct position with my current university? I have seen many people in our university who have held adjunct positions for a few years when they left the university but I have no information about the detailes and what they can do both academically and financially.

Comment: This is a question for the finder.  We can’t give you permission.

Comment: @Buffy: I am just asking for your experience and opinion.

Comment: Sorry, but both are irrelevant to your situation.

Comment: Depends up on your specific university and their policies as well as local politics.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly common, and universities have incentive to help, as they get overhead on the grants that stay at their institution.

My experience: I received a grant right when I switched universities that couldn't come with me. I kept an adjunct position at the old university while spending out the funds in the grant (for a graduate student that continued there). You just have to maintain good communication lines with the old school to ensure they can help you with spending/reimbursement.

But, I it could be very difficult to spend these funds if you don't have a good collaborator or students remaining at the university.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience with me. Were there any limitations on, for example, which items the fund can be used? Can it be used for travel and summer salary as defined in the proposal?

Comment: This would depend on the grant and the situation. I took travel but no salary.